# mySql subquery to sum the many records of one item of a select?

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called product and a table called sold.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to use one query to find all products and then for each product fond return in the result set a sum of sold.amount as total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very basic SQL join operation:

```
select product.id, sum(sold.amount)
from product
left join sold ON product.id = sold.product_id
group by product.id
```

if you want to list only products which have at least one sale, then change 'left join' to 'inner join'.

Comment: Many thanks. Now lets say I wanted to add another couple of sums but this time only for a specific date range. So I need a day sum and an all time sum.

Comment: @hcker2000 Don't try to pack too much into a single query (you will probably make the query less efficient than it could be). You want to fetch data off two criteria, so issue separate queries.

Comment: Thanks I will just break it out into two queries.

Comment: @hcker: that'd be done in the where clause, something like `WHERE DATE(sold.purchasedate) = '2011-11-18')` or `WHERE DATE(sold.purchasedate) BETWEEN '2011-11-11' AND '2011-11-28'`